# Android Counter Application Score List

Tags: android, list, counter

This is the interface of an application i am trying to succeed the last days.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyA3x.jpg]

It is just a simple counter, of a card game. I have managed to create the buttons, do the counting and show it in a different textview, stoping in a limit i wanted.

The thing is, that i want the scores of each round separetely, to be shown until the end of the game, like a list i draw in ms paint for preview.

I have managed to put the score in the 1st round on the txt1 and txt2 fields, but i cant figure out, how to put the 2nd round on txt3 and txt4 field, the 3rd on txt5 and txt6 field etc.

This is the code i ve created, of the void that puts the txt1 and txt2 into that fields.

```
private void setScore() {
    Double skor1 = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
    Double skor2 = Double.parseDouble(editText2.getText().toString());
    txt1.setText(Double.toString(skor1));
    txt2.setText(Double.toString(skor2));

    while (telikoOmada1 < 64 && telikoOmada2 < 64) {
        skor1 = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
        skor2 = Double.parseDouble(editText2.getText().toString());
        telikoOmada1 = telikoOmada1 + skor1;
        telikoOmada2 = telikoOmada2 + skor2;
        telikoTxt1.setText(Double.toString(telikoOmada1));
        telikoTxt2.setText(Double.toString(telikoOmada2));
        editText1.setText(null);
        editText2.setText(null);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you do the same but with telikoTxt3 and editText3 etc?

Comment: Left and Right of the Button on the image, there are TextViews that i put the score of each team. Every time i press that Button, it puts the scores given in txt1 and txt2.

I guess i must use and array or something, because the only thing i can imagine, is creating a different Button for every round, so when i add the scores again, i just say to the button to add the on txt3 and txt 4, and a 3rd button for txt5 and txt6 etc..